# Multiple bean context files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a Spring application with multiple context files defining my beans.

I have observed the context files are being loaded alphabetically by name

a.xml is loaded then b.xml etc

Can anyone confirm this is the default behavior?

I'm using Spring 3.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is strictly Spring 3.1 behavior but the Spring bean context files have been loaded alphabetically on multiple systems running multiple OS's (Windows and Linux).

Does my reputation increase for answering my own question?